# Type error: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str when looping through dictionary

Tags: python

In short, I get the above error when attempting to loop through the key-value pairs in a dictionary. I know the fix, but not the reason why.

```py
webuser = {
    "username": "JWick",
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Wick",
}

for key in webuser.items():
    print("\nKey: " + key)
```

Correct:

```py
for key, value in webuser.items():
    print("\nKey: " + key)
    print("value: " + value)
```

Is this because I am attempting to loop through two values and only using one variable to store & output? That way, the program attempts to concatenate the data in the dictionary in the variable and fails.

Comment: The reason why is because with `for key in webuser.items()` each value of `key` is a tuple since that is what the `items()` method of a dictionary returns. What don't you understand?

Comment: if you only want to get a key, you can always iterate over `.keys()` instead of `.items()`

Comment: @WitekBobrowski: If all you want is the keys you can just iterate over the dictionary directly: i.e. `for key in webuser:`

Comment: Thanks both, the book i'm using to learn didn't explain that the .items() method created a tuple which threw me off. Using .keys() will be useful in future so thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any iteration, `.items()` gives you a tuple which is `(key, value)` pair. If you do:

```
for k in webuser.items():
    ...
```

`k` becomes a tuple which is `(key, value)` Obviously you can't concatenate `str` and `tuple`. But if you do:

```
for k, v in webuser.items():
    ...
```

That tuple which gets back from `.items()` gets unpacked and the items inside it go into `k` and `v` and because they are `str` you can do concatenation.

Don't forget to print the for loop variables to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.items()` contains tuples of `(key,value)` as elements that cannot be concatenated directly with strings. Look the the demo below for one iteration of the loop:

```
webuser = {
    "username": "JWick",
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Wick", 
}


for item in webuser.items():
    print(item)
    key, value = item
    print("\nKey: " + key)
    print("value: " + value)
    break
```

Output:

```
('username', 'JWick')

Key: username
value: JWick
```

This shows that the items are coming in as tuples. were are then using multiple assignment `key, value = item` to unpack the key and value. Instead, you can directly do:

```
for key, value in webuser.items():
    ...
```

In your original example you only wanted to iterate over keys. You can do that in the following two ways:

```
for key in webuser:
    ...
```

OR

```
for key in webuser.keys():
    ...
```

NOTE: As demonstrated in the first one, iterating over a dictionary iterates over it's keys by default.

Answer (score 0):

To get a key in dictionary, there are 2 ways:

1. Iterate over the dictionary: `for key in webuser`
2. Use `.keys()` : `for key in webuser.keys()`

For getting the values of the dictionary: `.values()` is used `for key in webuser.values()`

For getting both the keys and values of the dictionary: `items()` is used.
`for key in webuser.items()`. It returns a tuple.

When you don't use 2 variables, the tuple is not unpacked and it is assigned to variable `key`.

But `for key,values in webuser.items()`, the tuple is unpacked and the keys are assigned to `key` and values are assigned to `values`

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary `items()` method returns a tuple of 2 elements for each iteration.

In short, a tuple is a data structure which is kind of an inmutable list of heterogeneous items (in the tuple each element represents a different concept while in a list they are all supposed to have the same nature. This is a good practice, not a technical limitation though). You can access to the items of a tuple by index, with the same notation you would do with a list.

So, you could get the same result with:

```
for item in webuser.items():
    print("key: " + item[0])
    print("value: " + item[1])
```

or

```
for item in webuser.items():
    print(f"key: {item[0]}; value: {item[1]}")
```

When you use 2 variables in the for assignment, Python is smart enough to positionally match each element of the tuple with the variables.